# Letter recommender hasn't responded to request and has conference deadline coming up. Should I remind them?

Tags: recommendation-letter

The title is a bit lengthy but captures the crux of the issue. I made a bit of a hasty decision to apply to PhD programs this round rather late (last Thursday) and sent potential letter writers a request on Friday. One of them is my advisor, another is a professor who I've worked with briefly, and the last is a professor who's not in my field but has known me personally for a while.

The second professor hasn't responded, and I'm beginning to worry. It has only been 5-6 days since I sent the request, but there is also a deadline coming up for a major conference on the 16th.

I also made the mistake of not including the deadlines in the initial email. The deadline for application is December 1st, so there isn't much time.

I'm wondering if I should follow up this week with a reminder, or if I should go in person.

Any feedback or opinions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Confused, what does the conference have to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sent the request last Friday. It is now Wednesday, i.e., the third working day after the request. That is not a lot of time at all, in the calendar of a professor. Moreover, the deadline is on December 1, which is still almost four weeks away.

Give the professor at least one more week. Maybe then send a reminder, and mention the deadline in that reminder.